# GridView bound to Datatable- Paging does not work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a webform set up with a button click that parses a .txt file and puts it in a datatable. when the parsing ends the datatable is bound to the gridview. I tried to add paging since I get tons of rows but it does not seem to work properly. Whenever I click on the next page the grid disappears and for it to appear again on the correct page I need to click on the button again.

I tried adding the following code to the source :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="true"
     AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" >
```

and this bit :

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; 
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

but it doesn't seem to change anything. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to add specific page size like `PageSize="10"`

Comment: I did, I also have an option to change the page size accordingly, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add OnPageIndexChanging Event inside GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="5">
```

and your aspx.cs code. Try to Bind Gridview on Page_Load Event.

```
  protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { this.BindGrid();}

 private void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From [dbo].[your table] "))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I add AutoGenerateColumns="false" the gridview doesn't even load. And I tried what you suggested, doesn't work.

Comment: i think your `Page_Load ` Event can't populate data on page changed try to load Gridview on `Page_Load ` event.

Comment: I've added the following :
If( GridView1.Rows.Count>0)
LogGrid();

LogGrid is the function that creates the datatable and populates it. That fixes the problem, However - I dont want this function to work each page load. there has to be another option, doesn't it?

Comment: @Freebirdy write your event like i have posted in my answer.

Comment: How does that help you? I dont want to re-load the datatable event each page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        //here yo have to assign datasource 
       //Some thing like this
       ///GridView1.DataSource=DataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Already did that, doesn't work since the DataTable isn't saved outside the button click function.